# header location php not redirecting page

Tags: php, header

I have the following code in my login script in PHP. When I put in the email and password required for login the page refreshes instead of redirecting me to page.php. The code initially required to select data from a different table eg, grade. If the query string is changed back to the previous table name then the code works. Now I have a different table set up and thought that changing the table name in the query should do that job, but it isnt. Please help.

```
  <?php
include ('database_connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    // Initialize a session:
    session_start();
    $error = array(); //this aaray will store all error messages
    if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) {//if the email supplied is empty 
        $error[] = 'You forgot to enter  your Email ';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
            $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
        } else {
            $error[] = 'Your Email Address is invalid  ';
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
    } else {
        $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    }
    if (empty($error)) {//if the array is empty , it means no error found
        $query_check_credentials = "SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE (email='$Email' AND password='$Password')";
        $result_check_credentials = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_credentials);
        if (!$result_check_credentials) {//If the QUery Failed 
            echo 'Query Failed ';
        }
        if (@mysqli_num_rows($result_check_credentials) == 1) {//if Query is successfull  // A match was made.
            $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC); //Assign the result of this query to SESSION Global Variable  

            header("Location:pageX.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            echo $email;
            echo $password;
            $msg_error = 'Either Email address or Password is Incorrect';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
        foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

            echo '  <li>' . $values . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ol></div>';
    }


    if (isset($msg_error)) {

        echo '<div class="warning">' . $msg_error . ' </div>';
    }
    /// var_dump($error);
} // End of the main Submit conditional.
?>
```

Comment: I'm having a _really_ hard time reading your code. Your indentation is all over the place. Use a proper IDE with auto-formatting, or see if you can fix it manually.

Comment: and what did u get with `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: Clearly `@mysqli_num_rows($result_check_credentials)` does not equal 1

Comment: Please read php.net ç_ç mysqli_num_rows doesn't always works... please put the record inside an array and count, or do a count(*) with another query to check the value

Comment: @Anthony D'Andrea I guess you are right. But I simply cant put my finger on it. Could you please give a hint.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection does not work because the value of the `Location:` header must be an absolute URI, i.e. it must start with the protocol. `pageX.php` is a relative URI and, while some browsers do their best to guess what the programmer wanted, others just stick to the standards and, as you said, don't redirect.

Try something like this:

```
header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/pageX.php');
```

and it will work like a charm.

Comment: Didn't know that o_o i'd save your answer for dynamic redirect ^_^ +1

Comment: Hmmm... it seems the latest version of the [HTTP RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231) allows relative URIs in the [`Location:`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header. This new RFC is only 6 months old and I don't know if any browser implements it yet. I would stay safe and still put absolute URIs on the `Location:` header on the next couple of years.